# How to create a procedure to insert values into a newly added column?

Tags: loops, stored-procedures, plsql, cursor

Here I need to create a procedure to insert values into a newly added column. This table has two primary keys. company_no and part_no.This table has 10 records and I need to update the newly added column as shown below.

```
 new_col = quantity * price;
```

This quantity and the price fields are columns which included in the same table. I already added the new column into the table and having a trouble in creating a procedure to update the newly added column. Do I need to use cursors and loops here? If yes could you please tell me how to do this.

Comment: @LittleFoot Could you please clarify this issue for me

Comment: You shouldn't store anything that can be easily calculated at run time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you don't need any procedure as everything can be done with a single `update` statement:

```
update that_table set
  new_col = quantity * price;
```

---

On the other hand, storing such a value is *bad practice*. You can

- always calculate it if needed (in a `select` statement), or
- create a view (which contains calculated value), or
- add a *virtual column* to the table

---

If it has to be a procedure:

```
create or replace procedure p_set_col is
begin
  update that_table set
    new_col = quantity * price;
end;
/
```

and run it as

```
begin
  p_set_col;
end;
/
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification given. But according to the question, I have to create a stored procedure. Could you please explain that way as well.

Comment: Have a look at edited answer, please.